# Props sent from child to parent return last value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm passing props from child to parent component but the value I get in parent component are last sent values.

Parent Component

```
const Page = () => {
    const optionsList = ['All', 'Web', 'App', 'Animation', 'Icons'];
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState('All');
    let selected = (value) => {
        setSelectedOption(value);
        console.log(selectedOption)
    }
    return (
        <Layout>
            <div className="container">
                <Options options={optionsList} selected={selected}/>
                {designType}
            </div>
        </Layout>
    );
}
```

Child component

```
const Options = ({options, selected}) => {
    const [isDropDownVisible,
        setIsDropDownVisible] = useState(false);
    const [selectedOption,
        setSelectedOption] = useState('All');
    return <div className="dropdown">
        <div className="select" onClick={e => setIsDropDownVisible(!isDropDownVisible)}>
            <span>{selectedOption}</span>
        </div>
        {isDropDownVisible && <ul className="options">
            {options.map((option, index) => (
                <li
                    key={index}
                    onClick={() => {
                        setSelectedOption(option);
                        setIsDropDownVisible(!isDropDownVisible);
                        selected(selectedOption);
                }}>{option}</li>
            ))
}
        </ul>}
    </div>;
}
```

If `All` is the current selected option then it will be consoled instead of the newly selected option `Animation` and if `App` is selected then `Animation` option will show in console.

Comment: Because `useState` is an async function and at that moment that you call the callback function it is not guaranteed that the state is updated. You should either use `useRef` or better do not duplicate the `useState` in the child, as you have already have passed every needed thing down to child

Answer (score 1):

Ok, pasting my comment once more here: Because useState is an async function and at that moment that you call the callback function it is not guaranteed that the state is updated. You should either use useRef or better do not duplicate the `useState` in the child, as you have already passed every needed thing down to the child

```
const Options = ({options, selected}) => {
    const [isDropDownVisible, setIsDropDownVisible] = useState(false);

    return (<div className="dropdown">
        <div className="select" onClick={e => setIsDropDownVisible(!isDropDownVisible)}>
            <span>{selectedOption}</span>
        </div>
        {isDropDownVisible && 
          <ul className="options">
            {options.map((option, index) => (
                <li
                    key={index}
                    onClick={() => {
                        setIsDropDownVisible(!isDropDownVisible);
                        selected(option);
                }}>{option}</li>
            ))
          }
        </ul>}
    </div>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the Child component to [uncontrolled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).